Book (series?) about female werewolf who summons a demon
I read a book a few years ago and its sequels but cannot remember the name.
The main character is a werewolf who is treated horribly by her clan. She calls out a name of some demon that her clan are all afraid of. The demon appears and takes her to his realm which has a magical library and a bunch of portals to different realms.
The demon has fire as his power but his flames can't hurt her. The demon's his mother ends up trying to destroy the universe and erases his memory and puts the werewolf back on earth with her werewolf pack.  She has to find a way to get back to his realm and make him remember her. She ends up finding a doorway in an old house that is still open and goes back.
